# Display two variables in a histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data set

```
structure(list(Latitude = c(8.983, 44.3498, 50.9332, 36.1333, 
35.7833, 37.65, 35.7667, 39.1332, 5.2833, 3.65, -0.05, -25.41666667, 
-44.63333333, -39.73333333, -14.9, -23.93333333, -39.83333333, 
-53.038, -43.308, -48.008, -47.533, -46.448, -45.037, -43.953, 
-41.02, -39.515, -45.022, -47.128, -47.988, -49.378, 24.5, -43.78, 
-43.63, -55.33, -44.77, -39.38, -36.75, -46.53, -49.33, -51.08, 
-47.77, -45.42, -41.37, 17.883, 45.1, 54.983, -43.03, -34.33, 
-34.92, -36.48, -28.07, -49, -42.58, -25.49, -46.6, -49.92, -46.1, 
59.6532, 53.867, 63.4832, 42.467, 38.917, 40.767, 31.383, 31.433, 
-22.98, 14.3, -39.2, -35.88, -4.3, -2.833, -0.633, 60.033, -33.2, 
-33.35, -33.35, -46.02, -45, -37.15, -29.73, -31.05, -31.63, 
-32.38, -30.2, -28.883, -28.017, -31.53, 12.383, 58.367, 60.733, 
-33.23, -38.98, -20.58, -38.57, 38.75, -29.52, -21.83, 2, 1.417, 
-21.98), Longitude = c("51.733", "-30.267", "-41.75", "-68.9167", 
"-68.9333", "-72.95", "-69.0833", "-42.65", "-17.0667", "-18.3", 
"-24.1667", "70.4", "70.96666667", "67.88333333", "70.2", "73.88333333", 
"75.05", "119.735", "105.548", "114.478", "114.423", "114.417", 
"114.348", "114.368", "100.012", "83.723", "95.082", "95.08", 
"95.037", "94.832", "-16.95", "46.2", "51.267", "65.467", "92.417", 
"104.37", "120.9", "125.57", "127.12", "129.97", "123.1", "121.12", 
"114.13", "58.083", "-10.57", "-15.4", "57.35", "54.217", "67.583", 
"69.55", "95.967", "-4.6", "-17.8", "11.307", "7.625", "-15.57", 
"-13.23", "-22.77", "-21.1328", "-0.0667", "-54.9", "-57.13", 
"-64.6", "-11.62", "-64.17", "7.017", "51", "13.5", "15.917", 
"64.817", "66.3", "69.45", "-50.83", "15", "16.433", "16.433", 
"44.367", "45.767", "43.5", "79.567", "82.85", "83.8", "84.85", 
"91.717", "92.833", "95.183", "99.25", "-18.92", "-47.73", "-57.83", 
"15.983", "29.933", "63.533", "140.62", "-67.55", "9.583", "10.8", 
"-5.25", "-9.083", "68.483"), Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35 = c("1", 
"8", "94", "1", "1", "6", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "64", 
"4", "3", "1", "12", "232", "50", "93", "88", "54", "43", "23", 
"21", "14", "49", "74", "76", "78", "2", "41", "163", "264", 
"24", "4", "6", "35", "20", "59", "26", "20", "1", "1", "4", 
"2", "27", "4", "5", "4", "4", "364", "9", "6", "118", "386", 
"146", "25", "32", "138", "34", "5", "22", "2", "2", "5", "1", 
"3", "5", "2", "1", "2", "310", "4", "3", "6", "109", "97", "2", 
"6", "3", "5", "6", "3", "1", "1", "2", "2", "378", "374", "2", 
"2", "1", "3", "3", "4", "15", "1", "3", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

and then I want to plot the latitude on the x-axis against the number of Neoglobya Pachyderma on the y-axis for which I have the code

```
library(ggplot2)

hist <-ggplot(data=daten_neu, aes(x = Latitude, y = Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35 )) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5, fill = "lightblue", color = "black", alpha = 0.7) +
  labs(title = "Abundance of Neglobina Pachyderma vs Latitude",
       x = "Latitude",
       y = "Abundance") +
  theme_minimal()

print(hist)
```

However, I get an error message to which I cannot find an answer here:

```
Error in `geom_histogram()`:
! Problem while computing stat.
ℹ Error occurred in the 1st layer.
Caused by error in `setup_params()`:
! `stat_bin()` must only have an x or y aesthetic.
```

Question Update:
The Dataset which I use is much bigger (I don´t know how to disply it)
However if I Use the Answer given my Histogram Looks like that:
[image]

My quess is that there are more Points per Latitude as thought is there a way to combine them first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update after clarification: This should work:

```
library(ggplot2)

daten_neu %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Latitude)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5,  
                 fill = "lightblue", 
                 color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Abundance of Neglobina Pachyderma vs Latitude",
       x = "Latitude",
       y = "Count") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

**First answer:**
Maybe you want a bar plot:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = daten_neu, aes(x = factor(Latitude), y = Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35))+
  geom_col( fill = "lightblue", color = "black", alpha = 0.7)+
  labs(title = "Abundance of Neogloboquadrina Pachyderma vs Latitude",
       x = "Latitude",
       y = "Abundance") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Just add this : `scale_x_continuous(limits = c( -90,90 ),  breaks = c(-90, 0, 90))`

Comment: maybe better a new question with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: oki I posted the Question:) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77854159/plot-many-plots-in-a-non-symmetrical-way-in-r-in-a-multiplot