# Plot many plots in a non-symmetrical way in R in a multiplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Hi I now have 3 individual plots one plot is a map one plot represents the number of points on the map in terms of latitude and one plot represents the number of points on the map in terms of longitude.

For this I use the data and the code as in the question .https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77850747/display-two-variables-in-a-histogram/77850965?noredirect=1#comment137251801_77850965

```
structure(list(Latitude = c(8.983, 44.3498, 50.9332, 36.1333, 
35.7833, 37.65, 35.7667, 39.1332, 5.2833, 3.65, -0.05, -25.41666667, 
-44.63333333, -39.73333333, -14.9, -23.93333333, -39.83333333, 
-53.038, -43.308, -48.008, -47.533, -46.448, -45.037, -43.953, 
-41.02, -39.515, -45.022, -47.128, -47.988, -49.378, 24.5, -43.78, 
-43.63, -55.33, -44.77, -39.38, -36.75, -46.53, -49.33, -51.08, 
-47.77, -45.42, -41.37, 17.883, 45.1, 54.983, -43.03, -34.33, 
-34.92, -36.48, -28.07, -49, -42.58, -25.49, -46.6, -49.92, -46.1, 
59.6532, 53.867, 63.4832, 42.467, 38.917, 40.767, 31.383, 31.433, 
-22.98, 14.3, -39.2, -35.88, -4.3, -2.833, -0.633, 60.033, -33.2, 
-33.35, -33.35, -46.02, -45, -37.15, -29.73, -31.05, -31.63, 
-32.38, -30.2, -28.883, -28.017, -31.53, 12.383, 58.367, 60.733, 
-33.23, -38.98, -20.58, -38.57, 38.75, -29.52, -21.83, 2, 1.417, 
-21.98), Longitude = c("51.733", "-30.267", "-41.75", "-68.9167", 
"-68.9333", "-72.95", "-69.0833", "-42.65", "-17.0667", "-18.3", 
"-24.1667", "70.4", "70.96666667", "67.88333333", "70.2", "73.88333333", 
"75.05", "119.735", "105.548", "114.478", "114.423", "114.417", 
"114.348", "114.368", "100.012", "83.723", "95.082", "95.08", 
"95.037", "94.832", "-16.95", "46.2", "51.267", "65.467", "92.417", 
"104.37", "120.9", "125.57", "127.12", "129.97", "123.1", "121.12", 
"114.13", "58.083", "-10.57", "-15.4", "57.35", "54.217", "67.583", 
"69.55", "95.967", "-4.6", "-17.8", "11.307", "7.625", "-15.57", 
"-13.23", "-22.77", "-21.1328", "-0.0667", "-54.9", "-57.13", 
"-64.6", "-11.62", "-64.17", "7.017", "51", "13.5", "15.917", 
"64.817", "66.3", "69.45", "-50.83", "15", "16.433", "16.433", 
"44.367", "45.767", "43.5", "79.567", "82.85", "83.8", "84.85", 
"91.717", "92.833", "95.183", "99.25", "-18.92", "-47.73", "-57.83", 
"15.983", "29.933", "63.533", "140.62", "-67.55", "9.583", "10.8", 
"-5.25", "-9.083", "68.483"), Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35 = c("1", 
"8", "94", "1", "1", "6", "1", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", "64", 
"4", "3", "1", "12", "232", "50", "93", "88", "54", "43", "23", 
"21", "14", "49", "74", "76", "78", "2", "41", "163", "264", 
"24", "4", "6", "35", "20", "59", "26", "20", "1", "1", "4", 
"2", "27", "4", "5", "4", "4", "364", "9", "6", "118", "386", 
"146", "25", "32", "138", "34", "5", "22", "2", "2", "5", "1", 
"3", "5", "2", "1", "2", "310", "4", "3", "6", "109", "97", "2", 
"6", "3", "5", "6", "3", "1", "1", "2", "2", "378", "374", "2", 
"2", "1", "3", "3", "4", "15", "1", "3", "2")), row.names = c(NA, 
-100L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I use the code:

```
library(ggrepel)
library(ggOceanMaps)
library(ggspatial)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(ggplot2)
library(leaflet)
library(gridExtra)



map <- basemap(c(-180, 180, -90, 90),  bathy.style = "rcb")+
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = daten_neu, aes(x = as.numeric(Longitude), y = as.numeric(Latitude), color = as.numeric(Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35))
  )+
  scale_color_gradient(
    name = "Nr. of Neogloboquadrina pachyderma",
    breaks = seq(0, 300, 50),
    labels = c(seq(0, 250, 50), ">300"),
    low = "darkred", high = "darkblue",
    limits = c(NA, 300),
    oob = scales::oob_squish
  )+ 
  theme(panel.ontop = FALSE
  )

# Display Neos vs Lat
lathist<-daten_neu %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Latitude)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5,  
                 fill = "lightgray", 
                 color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Abundance of Neogloboquadrina pachyderma vs Latitude",
       x = "Latitude",
       y = "Count")+
       xlim(-90, 90)+ 
  theme(panel.ontop = FALSE
  )  + coord_flip()+
  theme_minimal()

# Display Neos vs Long
longhist<- daten_neu %>% 
  mutate(across(everything(), ~as.numeric(.))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Longitude)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 5,  
                 fill = "lightgray", 
                 color = "black") +
  labs(title = "Abundance of Neogloboquadrina pachyderma vs Longitude",
       x = "Longitude",
       y = "Count")+
  xlim(-180, 180) +scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-180,180),  breaks = c(-180, -70, -60, -50, -40, -30, -20, -10, 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70))+

  theme_minimal()

multiplot <- grid.arrange(
  lathist,
  map,
  longhist,
  layout_matrix = rbind(c(1, 2), c(3, 3))
)

print(multiplot)
```

My code output looks like this:
[image]

But I want to create something like this but unfortunately I don't know much about the multplot concept

[image]

Comment: Have you considered `ggExtra::ggMarginal()` ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/29354374/646761 )? Though it's somewhat opinionated regarding legend positioning ( https://github.com/daattali/ggExtra/issues/60 ) and works best if you are OK with changing the legend position to bottom or left.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several options to glue multiple plots. My personal favorite is `patchwork` which using the `design=` argument allows to set the layout to arrange the plots and which via `guides="collect"` allows to put the legend on the right as in your desired result. Additionally I used `guide_area()` to restrict the legend to the first row of the patch:

```
library(patchwork)

design <-
"
BBBAD
CCC##
"

list(
  lathist,
  map,
  longhist,
  guide_area()
) |> 
  wrap_plots(
    guides = "collect",
    design = design,
    heights = c(3, 1)
  )
```

[image]

**UDPATE**

```
library(patchwork)

design <-
  "
BAD
C##
"
map <- map +
  scale_color_gradient(
    name = "Nr. of\nNeogloboquadrina\npachyderma",
    breaks = seq(0, 300, 50),
    labels = c(seq(0, 250, 50), ">300"),
    low = "darkred", high = "darkblue",
    limits = c(NA, 300),
    oob = scales::oob_squish
  )

lathist <- lathist +
  theme(
    plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 20, 5.5),
    plot.title = element_text(
      margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 20, 5.5)
    )
  ) +
  labs(
    title = "Abundance of\nNeogloboquadrina\npachyderma\nvs Latitude"
  )

list(
  lathist,
  map,
  longhist,
  guide_area()
) |>
  wrap_plots(
    guides = "collect",
    design = design,
    heights = c(5, 1),
    widths = c(8, 1, 1)
  )
```

[image]

Comment: this looks quite nice However is there a way to change the X (Space) A Histogram covers -> So that the Lat Histo becomes much narrower? And That the Plots do have the similar szise so for example that the Lat Histo is as large as the map in the Y direction?

Comment: Well, unfortunately this always requires some fiddling (which is up to you) and in the end depends on the size you want to use to export your plot. I just made an edit showing some of the parameters and things you could try, i.e. you can play around with the heights and widths for the patch. Also I would recommend to wrap your titles. Finally, I increased the bottom margin for the plot title and the plot for the lathist plot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how we can do it with `patchwork()`:
To split the map and the legend we extract the legend from the map:
Then we can playaround to arrange with patchwork package (see also @stefan s solution):

```
map <- basemap(c(-180, 180, -90, 90),  bathy.style = "rcb")+
  ggspatial::geom_spatial_point(
    data = daten_neu, aes(x = as.numeric(Longitude), y = as.numeric(Latitude), color = as.numeric(Neogloboquadrina_pachyderma...35))
  )+
  scale_color_gradient(
    name = "Nr. of Neogloboquadrina pachyderma",
    breaks = seq(0, 300, 50),
    labels = c(seq(0, 250, 50), ">300"),
    low = "darkred", high = "darkblue",
    limits = c(NA, 300),
    oob = scales::oob_squish
  )+ 
  theme(panel.ontop = FALSE
  )

my_legend <- get_legend(map)
only_legend <- as_ggplot(my_legend)

only_map <- map + theme(legend.position = "none")

only_map
only_legend


..... your other code


library(patchwork)

top_row <- only_map + lathist + only_legend
final_layout <- top_row / (longhist + plot_spacer()) + 
  plot_layout(ncol = 1, heights = c(4, 1))
final_layout
```

[image]

Comment: Hi TarJae I really like your answer. However, as I already mentioned with Steffan, I would like the proportions of my sketch to be followed? :D